# Marginal effect calculation after logistic regression with panel dataset using R

Tags: panel-data, random-effects-model, logit, fixed-effects-model, marginal-effect

I would like to perform a logit regression with a panel dataset, I know that the pglm package does the job, however, does anyone know if there is a standard package in R that allows me to calculate the marginal effects for a fixed effect or random effect logit (for panel data)?

Below is the documentation of the pglm package for R:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pglm/index.html